# Difference between REST and RPC

Tags: rest, rpc

I understand the underlying differences between REST and RPC, where REST has resources and works well with HTTP, but I wanted to know what are the main differences in terms of result. I can make a HTTP request or a RPC call but in the backend on the servers the requests still get fulfilled.

Are they just different abstractions for serving the same purpose or have I completely missed the point?

Comment: Yes, they're just different mechanisms for the same general concept.

Answer (score 1):

By REST the clients are loosely coupled to the implementation of the services and the services scale better. Those are the main differences.